# How to correctly set Airflow scheduler

Tags: python, scheduler, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to schedule tasks in airflow but apparently it's not so obvious.

The task I want to run is pretty simple, here is the DAG configuration:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='30 15 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 10, 3), catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, 
dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', 
python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

It means I want to run it every day at 15:30. If I put this task ON today, for instance, it doesn't trigger at 15:30, but will trigger tomorrow at this time. This is related to the idea of left-border of the interval of execution (quite a strange feature of Airflow).

So the question is:

How to trigger the task exactly today at 15:30 and not tomorrow at the end of the execution interval?

Any suggestions or clarifications would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created exactly the same DAG script today (2018-10-05T17:54:00+0). Airflow (v1.10) created a DAG run for 2018-10-04T15:30:00+0 (which should be executed at some time after 2018-10-05T15:30:00+0 [[0](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers)]) and started it immediately (because it was already after 2018-10-05T15:30:00+0). It did not create a DAG run for 2018-10-03T15:30:00+0 because of `catchup=False`, which instructs the scheduler to only create a DAG Run for the most current instance of the DAG interval series [[1](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup)].

So, the DAG run for today (2018-10-05) is the DAG run scheduled for 2018-10-04T15:30:00+0, because its scheduling interval ends today.

The reason why you do not see a DAG run for today (i.e., the one for 2018-10-04T15:30:00+0) in the Airflow Web UI in your case may be that you first set `start_date` to today, scheduled the DAG, and after that tried to change the `start_date` to an earlier day. The scheduler actually created a DAG run for an earlier date, but the Web UI just didn't display it. The easiest way to fix this is to change the `dag_id` (e.g., to `hello_world_2` etc.) when you change the `start_date` or `schedule_interval` [[2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls)] and restart the scheduler.

Comment: SergiyKolesnikov, thank you for your reply. Concerning the fact that I am not seeing the DAG for today - shouldn't restart of the airflow database help? That's what I was trying to do.

Comment: @NikitaVostrosablin You mean `airflow resetdb; airflow initdb`? It is quite intrusive and will remove other DAGs too, but, yes, that should help too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. I created a new DAG script (2018-10-05T22:22:00+0), restarted the database together with the webserver and the scheduler, putting `catchup=True`. This created two DAG runs for (10-03T15:30:00+00:00) and (10-04T15:30:00+00:00). No run for today :(

Comment: SergiyKolesnikov, According to the DAG interval series documentation, the `atomic execution series` are created by Airflow, and the current day can't appear until the interval will be complete (meaning tomorrow at the same time). So that's the problem - how do I run task if I need it exactly today?

Comment: @NikitaVostrosablin Actually, the DAG run for 10-04T15:30:00+00:00 will be executed at some time after 10-05T15:30:00+00:00. So this DAG run is actually for today, even though it is scheduled for yesterday. This is the most weird thing about Airflow, but this is how it works.

Comment: SergiyKolesnikov, yes, I got this somehow already and mentioned in my answer to this topic :) But anyway, thank you very much, you pushed my thoughts in a right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the idea.

According to [[1]](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup),  `atomic execution series` are created by Airflow. Every execution series has Execution Date which signify the beginning of the execution interval.

So in my case Execution Date (10-04T15:30:00+00:00) means the interval started 04th of October and ended 5th of October at the same time (*now*), executing today's task.